# Replace class name inside class attribute in HTML string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have HTML string and I want to replace specific class name with another. I want do it using regular expression. I found a way, to replace all strings inside HTML string, but I want to be sure that I will replace only this one inside class="...".

I have something like this:

```
export const replace = () => {
  const htmlString =
  '<di class="class-to-replace">\n<div class="row">\n <p>class-to-replace</p></div>\n</di>';

  const className = 'class-to-replace';
  const classReplacement = 'new-class';
  const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + className + '\\b', 'g');

  return htmlString.replace(regex, classReplacement);
};
```

And it works, however it replaces all the occurrences. How can I scope it only to class attribute so that changing the class name does not also affect the change of content?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) ... it starts `You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML.` ... and then descends into madness!!!

Comment: I don't have HTML. I am getting string from my backend, I think it's different scenario

Comment: you can't parse HTML with regex,regardless of where it comes from

Comment: I don't get it why? I want to adjust proper class name. I don't want to change the content of this HTML.

Comment: As the link suggests, there IS a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to use [DOMparser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to do this correctly

```js
const replace = (html, search, replace) => {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    doc.querySelectorAll(`.${search}`).forEach(el => el.classList.replace(search, replace));
    return doc.body.innerHTML;
};

const htmlString = '<di class="class-to-replace">\n<div class="row">\n <p>class-to-replace</p></div>\n</di>';
const className = 'class-to-replace';
const classReplacement = 'new-class';
console.log(replace(htmlString, className, classReplacement));
```

Comment: this is exactly what I mean, but I thought it could be implemented only using regexp itself. Unfortunately, I'm not good at this, hence my question here. Thank you for your help

Comment: @mati - updated the code to make it more like your attempt - you can probably write a `replace` function that takes `htmlString`, `className` and `classReplacement` as arguments to make it more general

Comment: actually @mati, rewritten to make `replace` generic :p

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I have HTML string and I want to replace specific class name with another. I want do it using regular expression. ...
>
>
>
> ... How can I scope it only to class attribute so that changing the class name does not also affect the change of content?*

Try the following *match pattern*.

```
(?<=class=(['"]))class-to-replace(?=\1)
```

```js
let s = '<di class="class-to-replace">\n<div class="row">\n <p>class-to-replace</p></div>\n</di>'
let p = /(?<=class=(['"]))class-to-replace(?=\1)/g
s = s.replace(p, 'new-class')

console.log(s)
```

For dynamic values, use the following.  Be sure to escape the `\1`.

```js
let s = '<di class="class-to-replace">\n<div class="row">\n <p>class-to-replace</p></div>\n</di>'
let a = 'class-to-replace', b = 'new-class'
let p = new RegExp(`(?<=class=(['"]))${a}(?=\\1)`, 'g')
s = s.replace(p, b)

console.log(s)
```